# Win7 64bit Ultimate, occasional video crashes

Tags: windows-7, drivers, video, 64-bit, bsod

I have occasional video crashes.
My Video will go black but retains sound.
Sometimes I get alarm or video freezes and the occasional BSOD.
I Ran Driver Verifier to try to figure out if it's a driver conflict.
But--I'm clueless as to what I'm looking at with the log file. (Using BlueScreenView to look at dump.)
I have a Win7 64bit Ultimate
HDMI 32" tv as monitor
AMD Radeon R7 260X 2gig GDDR5.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

> 070518-20280-01.dmp   7/5/2018 12:01:23 AM
>   SYSTEM_THREAD_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED   0x1000007e  ffffffff`80000003   fffff800`02f0d178   fffff880`0407d5f8   fffff880`0407ce60   fltmgr.sys  fltmgr.sys+1a960
>   Microsoft Filesystem Filter Manager   Microsoft® Windows® Operating
>   System    Microsoft Corporation   6.1.7600.16385
>   (win7_rtm.090713-1255)    x64 ntoskrnl.exe+ab177
>   C:\Windows\Minidump\070518-20280-01.dmp   4   15  7601    275,856 7/5/2018
>   12:03:06 AM

Comment: That is not a video driver crash, it's an OS kernel crash. Do you have the latest updates for the OS ?

Comment: fltmgr.sys is memory management, you have either bad system ram module or the memory on the video card itself is bad is my guess.

Comment: @Moab The problem here is neither in the OS kernel or in memory management. Fltmgr.sys is a manager, a sort of "wrapper", for file system minifilters. fltmgr.sys gets installed in the stack for every file system driver and then calls out to each registered file system minifilter. The usual cause of a crash in fltmgr.sys is a bad file system minifilter. File system minifilters are used by, for example, the "live scanning" component of e.g. anti-malware software . (fltmgr.sys itself is pretty darned reliable as it's used a LOT).

Comment: @LliamLliam Can you put your minidump on a public file sharing system and post a link?

Comment: Dump link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/udns2nz27ktw681/070518-20280-01.dmp?dl=0

Comment: @Overmind Yeah, I try to keep on top of updates.

Comment: @Jamie Hanrahan I've been having issues pretty much since the video card left warranty. :p

Answer (score 0):

The stack indicates that the last non-Microsoft component executed was aswMonFlt.sys. This is a file system minifilter driver, part of an antimalware package by Avast.

Try updating it. If that doesn't help, uninstall it and use something else.

It would be helpful if you could zip up your last half a dozen or so of the minidumps so I could see if they're consistent with this one.